# Load ajax/jquery JSON array into Twig Template

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

I am currently building a program using Symfony2 framework and also taking advantage of the many nice new features that come with the platform such as Doctrine, Twig etc.

One of my pages requires me to load  a big load of data via AJAX after pageload is complete. This is easily achieved uing JQuery/Ajax but i'd like to think that something like this would have a way of injecting ajax directly into the Twig template maybe via JSON and have it populate in a for loop.

```
<table>
<tr><td>header</td></tr>
{% for row in rows %}
    <tr><td>{{row.data}}</td></tr>
{%endfor%}
</table>
```

Something like this crude example.

I did browse the docs quickly for this but there search is down and i couldn't find anything directly. A link to documentation could suffice if its what im looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cleanest way would be to generate your Json in the controller.
Something around:

```
/**
 * @route("/json", name="json_generator")
*/
public function jsonAction() {
   // do your for loop and build up a $jsonArray

   return new Response( json_encode($jsonArray) );
}
```

And then test the response of this in the browser and load this with Javascript in the twig template.
Don't have the specific code right now, but from the top of my head:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
     ajax: true,
     url: "{{ path('/json') }}"
  });
};
```

Just so you get the idea. Hopefully it serves you as a base example-

Comment: This is how i figured, I was going for a cleaner option but im thinking maybe there isn't one. Which is strange as it strikes me as the type of thing that Symfony would implement.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 ways:
1. Make AJAX request, in controller render html and return it to the script. Then add when it is needed.
2. Make AJAX request, return JSON and build html in the script, then add ready html to your specific place.

I think better way is render html in your action and return it to your AJAX script